# Как в pyCharm использовать функцию fileinput.input()?

Tags: python, pycharm

Как в pyCharm использовать функцию `fileinput.input()`?
То есть каким образом можно указать на входящий файл?

```
i=1  
for line in fileinput.input():  
    path1 = line.rstrip("\n")  
    print("File #", i, path1)  
    i = i + 1
```

Вот например этот кусок кода, который я мог запускать в far manager, а сейчас хочу перейти на pyCharm, но тут не получается запустить этот код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in fileinput.input(["1.log", "2.py"]):
    print(line)
```

Comment: То есть придется вручную указывать путь к входящему файлу?

Comment: что значит вручную? используйте переменную или input()

Comment: понял, спасибо!